# Bearing of a line or a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Rochelle is 25 miles due south of Rockford,and North Chicago is 65 miles  due east of Rockford.Find the bearing of North Chicago From Rochelle.

I used Pythagorean theorem in solving this because i thought that the only one that is asked  in the question is the distance from south to east in terms of hypotenuse.I got 69.64 miles as the answer but as i searched the word "bearing",it has something to do with the angle so i am confused now if what is the correct answer.Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Try searching for the term "true bearing".

Answer (score 0):

The bearing from one point to another is the direction of the line between those points.
Usually in problems like these, where the principal directions are north, east, south, and west, the convention is that the direction due north is a bearing of $0$ degrees,
due east is $90$ degrees, due south is $180$ degrees, and due west is $270$ degrees.

For example, in this problem the bearing from Rockford to Rochelle is $180$ degrees
and the bearing from Rockford to North Chicago is $90$ degrees.

You can compute other bearings by measuring the angle that the line between the points
makes with the coordinate axes. It can be helpful to draw a right triangle in which
one leg runs north-south and the other runs east-west.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reckon : $\tan^{-1}\frac{65}{25} $ due West of Rochelle.